# missing HtmlIframe from System.Web.UI.HtmlControls

Tags: asp.net

Do you know what dll should i add as a reference to be able to use HtmlIframe?
i've checked some forums and they answered System.Web but i already add it as a reference and used "using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;" which i know had the HtmlIframe. and it keeps showing me this error:

The type or namespace name 'HtmlIframe' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but discovered the answer, see this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmliframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Basically, replacing

```
<iframe...
```

with

```
<asp:HtmlIframe
```

in the markup causes the designer to have the line, sadly an incorrect line of:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.HtmlIframe Iframe1;
```

The correct line to use is:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlIframe Iframe1;
```

Notice the change of "WebControls" to "HtmlControls".

With that simple change, you are good to go.